# Is there a way to change the directory in which screenshots are saved?

Tags: macos

Lets say I take a screen shot on a Mac, and no matter what, it is saved on my desktop. How can I change where the file is saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /path/to/new/folder/
```

(Note: according to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screenshot-in-os-x-lion), the trailing slash is required!)